# Video capture HTML page to stream

Tags: video, stream, capture

I would like to screen capture an html page into video and stream it live. I've found a way to do this using OBS: https://obsproject.com but I would like to use  this technology server side.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a C# application using Html2Canvas
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/
And any Rmtp streaming library. Of course if you are looking for a plug n play solution this is not it.